# PHP require path - same directory

Tags: php, include

I have index.html in the root and all supporting files in /HTML. I have Google analytics code in a file in the HTML directory. It works from my index.html with this code in between the head tags...

```
<?php
require('HTML/GoogleAnalytics.html');
?>
```

but not in any of the supporting files in the HTML directory, same directory as the file i'm trying to require/include with this code...

```
<?php
require('GoogleAnalytics.html');
?>
```

from PHP.net "...include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

From PHP 5.3 (which is at this time after end of life cycle) and later you can use also `__DIR__` constant , http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

```
require(__DIR__ . '/GoogleAnalytics.html');
```

Comment: replacing it with that line of code caused the page not to load at all. from the google site"PHP Implementation optional
Create a PHP file named "analyticstracking.php" with the code above and include it on each PHP template page. Then, add the following line to each template page immediately after the opening <body> tag:
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>" What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

To make it relative to the *current* file, you can prepend `dirname(__FILE__)` like so:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/GoogleAnalytics.html');
```

By default, paths are relative to the file that the request originated from.

Comment: I replaced my line of code with yours, and it didn't work. And I don't understand, it IS in the same place as the calling page/script. So I tried bumping it down one directory, so the file I want to include was in HTML/google/GoogleAnalytics.html. So it would have the same relationship as the index, where it worked. No luck. Index still worked when I added google to the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
require('/HTML/GoogleAnalytics.html');
```

Comment: You may be new to PHP? ... Anyway, PHP says: `Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument.` The same is true for `include_once`, `require`, and `require_once`.  Yes, it is common to find them used with parenthesis, but not needed. Look at some of the examples at PHP.net. It's not a problem if used, but you could get "tripped up" by some interviewers about the use, and some coding standards wherever you work may not allow them. See [this](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.including.php) too.

Comment: @PaulT. Every example in this page is using parenthesis.

Comment: @T30 yes, I know, I was only mentioning PHPs info. One of those personal style matters, I guess.